# Is it possible to hook into GDI+ and save all strings sent to DrawString?

Tags: gdi+

I need to get a large table (300K+ rows) from an application and there is no export function.
After a lot of unsuccessful attempts I'm left with a Copy Paste macro that goes one row at a time. If there is a way to get the strings as they are drawn I could get a page(40 rows) at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't doing this for commercial purposes, you can use [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) to hook into drawstring really easily.  There are some examples using detours on [CodingTheWheel's blog](http://www.codingthewheel.com/) series on a pokerbot.  Even if the Detours option is unavailable, there is tons of information on [windows api hooking](http://www.bing.com/search?q=windows+api+hooking) on the web.